# Prepopulate Username and Password in Login screen

Tags: authentication, passwords, credentials, ui-design

I have designed a standard login screen in ASP.NET like below:

[image]

As usual when operator selects “Remember me”, we expect system to not ask operator for credentials anymore and go directly to default (home) page.
My business team saw something on internet and they believe that when “Remember me” has been selected we need to pre populate the username and password and wait for customer to press “LOG IN” button:

[image]

I haven’t seen this practice so often and I am not very comfortable to do it. Although, I don’t have a good technical argument to explain and change their mind.
I am basically looking for good argument to explain cons and pros of above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever should you pre-populate a passwords edit field. If you do so, everybody is able to read the plain-text password, if he can open the login form on this computer. A few minutes on an unlocked office computer would be enough to check the browser history, afterwards the attacker can login whenever and whereever he wants.

If you have a remember me function, and the user has logged in using this function, then there is no need to display the login form at all. You can just display the content. In this case, an attacker can do things with the account, but he cannot login unnoticed later from somwhere else.

I think (hope) you saw the pre-populated password field, because the browser filled in the content, and not the website did it. Maybe there is a password manager installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I populate the password with digested hashed password which does not help attacker? I am in your favor too but I want to make a strong case.

Comment: @Barsham - If you pre-populate the stored hash from the database, the hash would actually become the password, it could be sent to the server directly to gain access.

Comment: Excellent I think you made my case.